# Replace string in filename while using convert

Tags: bash

I want to convert all files recursively which include a specific string in the filename. The specific string in the output filename should be replaced with another string.

I already got the first parts - but have no idea how to replace the string in the output filename.

Input files should include '-default-' in the filename which should be relaced by '-head-' in the output file.

Thanks for your help :)

```
find . -name '*-default-*' -print0 | xargs -0 -L 1 -I {} convert -compress JPEG -resize "238"  {} {}
```

Answer (score 2):

`xargs` has no facility for substituting parts of the input filename, but that is easy enough to work around. Run a simple shell script from `xargs` and you get the full repertoire of the shell at your disposal.

```
find . -name '*-default-*' -print0 | 
xargs -0 -L 1 -I {} bash -c 'f="{}"; 
    convert -compress JPEG -resize 238 "$f" "${f/-default-/-head-}"'
```

The `${var/str/subst}` syntax is a [bashism](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html#FTN.AEN6152); it will have to be somewhat more involved if you require POSIX compatible shell script.

If you have tricky file names which may contain e.g. double quotes, you might have to use a standalone script; something like this, perhaps:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f; do
    convert -compress JPEG -resize 238 "$f" "${f/-default-/-head-}"'
done
```

Then you could just `... | xargs ./script`

Comment: Note that this won't work if found filenames contain whitespace, or apostrophes, for example.

Comment: Right; added a pair of double quotes as a partial remedy, but this will still break if your file names contain e.g. double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

As tripleee notes, xargs doesn't support manipulating substituted filenames. However, a shell loop might do this and be a little easier to comprehend. Like this:

```
find . -name '*-default-*' |
    while IFS='' read -r f; do
        convert -compress JPEG -resize 238 "$f" "${f/-default-/-head-}"
    done
```

Assigning empty string to IFS prevents loss of leading and trailing whitespace. The "-r" switch to "read" disables interpreting backslash as an escape character. If you want to avoid the bashism noted by tripleee, use sed.